# FB.ui apprequests no response

Tags: apprequests

I use apprequests in an Facebook Canvas application. Most of the time, it works fine.

But for some people, only between specific senders and recipients (always the sames), it doesn't. In those cases, I don't have any response send to callback function not even an error message. If I change the sender (using another facebook account) or the recipient, it work. But it can also concern several recipients for a same sender.

Example

```
FB.ui({"method":"apprequests","title":"Send energy","message":"sent you Energy","to": XXXXXXX,"data":"eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjoyLCJmcm9tIjoiMTA3NDQ5OTk2NCIsImNoYW5uZWwiOiIxIiwiYmFjayI6dHJ1ZSwidHlwZSI6IkdJRlQifQ=="}, function(response){console.log(response)} )
```